# Reverse for 'results' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$']

Tags: python, django

I just got to the generic views section of the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial04/) on their website, but I'm stuck at this part and keep getting this error. This question has been answeared before, but for an older version of the tutorial and Django. I was hoping someone here could help me. Here is the code:

urls.py

```
app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name = 'vote'),
]
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    context = {
        'latest_question_list' : latest_question_list,
    }    
    return render(request, 'polls/index.html', context)

def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question' : question})

def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk = question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question_id' : question_id})

def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'question': question,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

detail.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }} </h1>
{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p> {% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method ="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name = "choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" >
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }} </label>
    <br>
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote">
</form>
```

results.html

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'polls:results' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

there is a specific message pointing to the last line of results.hmtl

```
In template C:\Users\Erenildo\Desktop 2\Python\Django\DjangoTut\Djanguiho\mysite\polls\templates\polls\results.html, error at line 9
```

edit1: 
models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: probably your `question.id` is not an integer. Try commenting out the `{% url 'polls:results' question.id %}` and printing the `question.id` at this point to see what you get. Another case might be that the question id should be a named param for the template: `{% url 'polls:results' question_id=question.id %}`

Comment: So, I tried removing the last line and it rendered a blank page. Then I tried just printing ```question.question_text``` also rendered a blank page. I guess it's a problem with the DB request? I edited the question inserting my models.py

Comment: See my answer below. `{{ question.id }}` and `{{ question.question_text }}` won't work in your results template because you have `{'question_id': question_id}`. It should be `{'question': question}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `results` view. You should include `question` in the template context, not `question_id`.

```
def results(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/results.html', {'question': question})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try just doing this for `results.py`

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url 'results' question_id=question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
```

So long as you only have one URL patterns with the namespace `results` then you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for trying to help! I really appreciate it

Comment: The problem is that `question.id` is evaluating to the empty string `''`, so changing from `question.id` to `question_id=question.id` won't help.